# Custom eqref with letter

Tags: math-mode, equations

On a specific equation, how can I customize the equation environment/referencing, such that

- The equation is numbered by as custom acronym, say "(NEW)" (instead of a squentially generated number, such as "(2)")
- When I refer with `\eqref{eq_label}` to the special equation, it displays (NEW) instead of the equation number?

Answer (score 5):

`\tag{}` does this for you. Remember to load `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
A normally numbered equation:
\begin{equation}
    1+2=3\label{normal}
\end{equation}
This is an equation:
\begin{equation}
    2+3=5\tag{NEW}\label{new}
\end{equation}
Since \eqref{new} and \eqref{normal}, we can see that blah so normal numbering again
\begin{equation}
    1\times2=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Superuser27: Thanks for the language correction!

Comment: You're welcome :) it's something my English teacher was very strict about: "remember to do" means "don't forget to do something in the future" whereas "remember doing" means "don't forget something that already happened".
So "remember adding" is like saying "remember that you added this" `:D`

Comment: @Superuser27 It is off-topic here, but in fact I'm always confused when dealing with "remember to do" vs "remember doing", "stop to do" vs "stop doing", etc.